# Gulp concatenate plugins and main scripts then minify

Tags: gulp

I'm hoping to combine everything into one minified JS file, with the contents of main.js right at the end. The below outputs a minified file int he correct destination, but it seems to ignore the order. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
// Filepaths
var themepath = 'wp/wp-content/themes/themename'


// optimise scripts
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    return gulp.src('build/scripts/**/*.js')
    .pipe(order(['build/scripts/plugins/**/*.js','build/scripts/main.js']))
    .pipe(concat('main-min.js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(plumber())
    .on('error', errorLog)
    .pipe(gulp.dest(themepath + '/assets/scripts/min/'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Try run uglify before concat. I think uglify messes with the order. So try the following:

```
// Filepaths
var themepath = 'wp/wp-content/themes/themename'


// optimise scripts
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    return gulp.src('build/scripts/**/*.js')
    .pipe(order(['build/scripts/plugins/**/*.js','build/scripts/main.js']))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(concat('main-min.js'))
    .pipe(plumber())
    .on('error', errorLog)
    .pipe(gulp.dest(themepath + '/assets/scripts/min/'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});
```

Comment: Nope. Still not behaving. The main.js contents still appear before the contents of the plugins folder

Answer (score 0):

Alright I figured it out.

Because you're specifying the order within an already predefined stream from gulp.src. You need to specify the order relative to the original gulp.src path, I.E. removed build/scripts from the order paths:

```
.pipe(order(['plugins/**/*.js', 'main.js']))
```

Comment: I added a pull request for the documentation to be updated, to explain this functionality a bit better: https://github.com/sirlantis/gulp-order/pull/27

Comment: This documentation change has now been merged in to the main gulp-order repository :)